# How to prove that the module of characteristic function is less than one

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

I would like to know if my resolution is right...
I want prove that

$|\varphi(t)| = \vert\mathbb{E}[e^{i t X}]\vert\leq 1$ , $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\it{proof:}$

First, note that $|\mathbb{E}[e^{i t X}]| \leq \mathbb{E}[|e^{i t X}|]$.

But, on the other side, we know that  $|e^{i t X}| = |\cos(tX)+ i \sin(tX)| = 1$. Then, $\mathbb{E}[|e^{i t X}|] = {\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}1dP} = P(\Omega) = 1$. So,

$|\varphi(t)| = \vert\mathbb{E}[e^{i t X}]\vert\leq  \mathbb{E}[|e^{i t X}|] = 1$

Comment: This looks fine.