# module of characteristic function <1

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

I have problems with this proof: [How to prove that the module of characteristic function is less than one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312644/how-to-prove-that-the-module-of-characteristic-function-is-less-than-one).

Why $\vert\mathbb{E}[^{}]\vert\le \mathbb{E}[\vert^{}\vert]$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities : $\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx\right|\le \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$

Comment: modulus is different from absolute value, right?
.

Comment: No, on complex numbers it's the same function, and this inequality is also valid for complex $f$ (and more generally for vector-valued $f$, if you replace the absolute value by the vector norm).